# How do I get mwc-icon-button working with font awesome?

Tags: font-awesome, web-component, polymer-2.x

I have the following...

```
<!-- Works -->
<i class="fab fa-linkedin" slot="actionItems"></i>
<!-- Does not work -->
<mwc-icon-button icon="linkedin" slot="actionItems"></mwc-icon-button>
```

Also tried variations like...

```
<mwc-icon-button icon="fa-linkedin" slot="actionItems"></mwc-icon-button>
<mwc-icon-button class="fab fa-linkedin" icon="linkedin" slot="actionItems"></mwc-icon-button>
```

But can't get it so what is the deal?

Comment: Where did you find the info that MWC should work with **another** icon(font) set? The [docs](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-components/tree/master/packages/icon) only says: *Material Icons*. I did [IconMeister](https://IconMeister.github.io) because cherry picking icons from different sets was a pain.

Comment: I just assumed they would I guess to your point I shouldn't do that lol